# Multiply a column by a constant stored as variable using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a macro in excel which does a bunch of basic calculations (multiplication, division, etc.) using columns from a table in Excel. My table looks like this:

[image]

The problem I have is that, as part of the calculations, the user needs to specify a constant "a" that will be used to obtain the values of a column named "Z2"with this expression: values in "Z2" = Values in column "X1"+ Values in column "Y2" multiplied by constant 'a'. In order to achieve this I tried with the following code:

```
Sub Macro_test()

Dim constant As Double
constant = InputBox("Insert constant 'a'")
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "X1"
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@X]*SIN[@Y]"
Range("E1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Y2"
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@X]*[@Y]*[@X1]"
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Z2"
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@X1]+[@Y2]*constant"
```

Everything works well but the operation that involves the constant does not work. Any idea on what am I doing wrong?. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You need to concatenate it in with `&` - see the linked duplicate.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Hi @BigBen I tried with ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@X1]+[@Y2]*" & constant & but it does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: Is your setup still the same (the table headers)?

Comment: Yes indeed, the table content will vary with time but the headers will be the same.

Comment: Hi @BigBen I found that I can store my variable in a cell inside my worksheet, run the calculations and then delete the cell value. Do you have any suggestion using "&" as you said?

Comment: I can't repro the error... works for me, if the table headers are exactly as in the screenshot.

Comment: Hi @BigBen wich expression are you using? is this one: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@X1]+[@Y2]*" & constant & ? with * inside the " " ?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Formula = "=[@X1]+[@Y2]*" & constant`.

Comment: Hej @BigBen man I was adding (without need) an extra & at the end of my statement. That's why I was getting an error!. Now I fixed it and it is working. Thanks man.